# If statement in javascript forms

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, if-statement

Im fairly new to javascript but have some experience in HTML. I am trying to create a form which allows me to select an option from the drop down menu, which further expands the form (showing new fields on the same page) depending on the option selected from the drop down menu. I figured I need some sort of if statement to achieve this but I can't seem to figure out the right way to do so. I already have the drop down menu working. I would put the code I already have on here, but for some reason its not letting me
Thanks for your help

**EDIT** - Ran the code from comments through HTML tidy

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />

  <title>Ipod Inventory</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function submitSelect(form) { alert (form.reason.selectedIndex); document.body.innerHTML() = "<h3>NEW STUFF<h3>"; } 
  //]]>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>General</h3>Employee Requesting:

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="employee" value="" />
  </form>

  <form name="myform" action="" method="get" id="myform">
    Reason: <select name="reason">
      <option>
        Conference/Meeting
      </option>

      <option>
        Loaner
      </option>
    </select> <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick=
    "submitSelect(this.form)" /><br />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not letting you? What happens when you paste the code into the question text box?

Comment: Go ahead and copy-paste your code in here, and it it doesn't quite look right, we'll help you in that department. No worries, mate!

Comment: Are you wanting to add/remove entire `<select>` boxes, or to add/remove `<option>`s from a single select box? That is, are you looking to add new elements to the form or just edit pre-existing elements?

Comment: Well here's the code, hope it shows

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Ipod Inventory</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function submitSelect(form) {
    alert (form.reason.selectedIndex);
    document.body.innerHTML() = "<h3>NEW STUFF<h3>";
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<h3>General</h3>
Employee Requesting:<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="employee" VALUE="">
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
Reason:

<SELECT NAME="reason">
<OPTION>
<OPTION>Conference/Meeting
<OPTION>Loaner
</SELECT>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="submit" Value="Submit"
onClick="submitSelect(this.form)">
<br />

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: You should use lowercase elements, such as `body`, `html`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, looks a lot better

Comment: Sorry, but you still haven't confirmed exactly what you want to do. From scanning the code, are you wanting to have another `select` (drop-down) menu appear once the reason has been selected? Or is the reason `select` box meant to change depending on the employee entered?

Comment: When the user selects an option from the reason select menu, a different set of form (text areas, new dropdown menus etc.) "appears" on the same page(without clearing the page). The set of form is specific to the option selected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want to do is start with the `onchange` event of your reason select box:

```
<select name="reason" id="reason" onchange="myFunc();">
```

`myFunc()` (excuse the name, I'm not very creative) will be where you do your showing/hiding of the other inputs - probably not a different *form*, as usually inputs are collected into a single form on a page. Each input (or set of inputs) should be in it's own `<div>` tag, and you can then use the `element.style.display` property of the tag to show/hide the inputs, as described in the other answers. For example, you might have the following in your form:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get" id="myform">
    Reason: <select name="reason" id="reason" onchange="myFunc()">
      <option>
        Conference/Meeting
      </option>
      <option>
        Loaner
      </option>
    </select> 
    <div id="conferenceInputs">
      Conference:
      <select name="conferenceSelectBox" id="conferenceSelectBox">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="loanerInputs">
      Loaner:
      <select name="loanerSelectBox" id="loanerSelectBox">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitSelect(this.form)" />
  </form>
```

The `myFunc()` javascript would look something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
  var selectElem = document.getElementById('reason');
  var optionText = selectElem.options[selectElem.selectedIndex].text;
  switch(optionText) {
    case "Conference/Meeting":
      document.getElementById('conferenceInputs').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('loanerInputs').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    case "Loaner":
      document.getElementById('loanerInputs').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('conferenceInputs').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

Finally, you would want to have a javascript function that loads with the HTML page - `<body onload="anotherFunc()">` that sets both `div`'s style.display properties to 'none' so that they don't appear before the user selects anything.

Comment: At whoever down-voted me, can you please explain why? I understand that down-voting is meant to be used for when something is wrong, and I gladly accept all corrections to my answer and will change it with credit, or delete it if it's that badly wrong. Given that I can copy/paste the above answer (and have done so) and get it to run fine, I am unsure what I may have done wrong.

Comment: Im not sure who down-voted you, but your answer is amazing. You continued CFP's answer and gave me a lot more details. I got sidetracked by a different assignment yesterday so I didnt finish writing the code for this one. This a big help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is split your page in different `div` sections, one for each case in your dropdown. You would then alter the `display` property of those `div`s using

```
element.style.display = 'none'
```

or

```
element.style.display = 'block'
```

If your setup is more complex, you might want to create a list of fields that should be visible for each item in your combo box, and then show/hide using the same technique.

For example, you would have a dropdown with male, and female. You would then have to `div` elements, whose `id` would be `male` or `female`. Then you would use

```
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById('selector').value == 'male') {
    document.getElementById('male').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('female').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('male').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('female').style.display = 'block';  
  }
}
```

Comment: this could work,but What kind of syntax should I use to tell the if statement that if "Conference/Meeting" option is selected display the specific div.

Comment: `if( document.getElementsByName('reason').value == "Conference/Meeting" ){ /* ... do stuff ... */ }`

Comment: Although, I might suggest checking the element exists first, just in case, like this : `if(  document.getElementsByName('reason') && document.getElementsByName('reason').value == "Conference/Meeting" ){ /* ... do stuff ... */ }`

Comment: thats actually quite helpful. I'm gonna research some more about creating and calling divs and try it out. Also how do I have the divs hidden when the webpage is first loaded. I understand how to make them appear through the if statement, just not sure how to keep them hidden.

Comment: My pleasure :) I found that page which seems quite useful: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/ You can then associate your function with the onchange event of your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
selectmenu.onchange=function(){ //run some code when "onchange" event fires
 var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex] //this refers to "selectmenu"
 if (chosenoption.value!="nothing"){
  window.open(chosenoption.value, "", "") //open target site (based on option's value attr) in new window
 }
}
```

Thats the if condition you need to use and the example also shows how to bind change event too..([code snippet extracted from javascript kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml))